# Redis and Logstash Logging Python

Tags: python, scrapy

**Redis Handler**

```
from logging import Handler


class RedisHandler(Handler):
    def __init__(self, config, redis):
        Handler.__init__(self)
        self.config = config
        self.redis = redis

    def emit(self, record):
        self.redis.lpush(self.config.get('logger', 'name'), self.format(record))



from logstash_formatter import LogstashFormatter
def get_logger():
    """

    :return: Logger
    """
    logger = logging.getLogger(get_config().get('logger', 'name'))
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    redis_handler = RedisHandler.RedisHandler(get_config(), get_redis())
    redis_handler.setFormatter(LogstashFormatter)
    logger.addHandler(redis_handler)

    return logger
```

I am trying to implement ELK for my scrapy project.

But somehow the `record` argument is coming as an instance of `LogRecord` instead of `LogstashFormatter`

> unbound method format() must be called with LogstashFormatter instance
>   as first argument (got LogRecord instance instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply an instance of a formatter, not a class. Change:

```
redis_handler.setFormatter(LogstashFormatter)
```

to

```
redis_handler.setFormatter(LogstashFormatter())
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro :)